# What if I want to ask a question that isn't appropriate on any SE site?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my [Game Development Stack Exchange post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/121726/game-boy-c-using-gbdks-rpn-calculator-keyboard-for-text-editing-game-boy-game).

What if a question cannot fit in with any site, or is marked off topic to any StackExchange community? What if it's not a question normally asked, or it's hard to find a solution, like mine? If I were to post it on other communities it will be marked as off-topic too. It's like this question is an oddball and a missfit from that Christmas story.

Seriously I don't know where it fits or how to ask it.

Answer (score 2):

If a question is off-topic on a given StackExchange site, it shouldn't be asked there (and will be closed, like yours, if it is). If a question is off-topic on *all* StackExchange sites, it shouldn't be asked on *any* StackExchange site.

The SE network is not about hosting *all possible* questions. It's about hosting a specific subset of all questions: those with objective answers (generally).

There are other places on the internet where you can ask questions that would be off-topic on all SE sites. For example, you could ask on [GDNet](http://www.gamedev.net).

Comment: so for what community can this question can be asked in because i have trouble with telling what community the question fits in.i used game development because is has to do with a game boy rom

Comment: i like the suggestion but i have trust issues with other sites because my instructor suggested stack exchange for my programming needs. btw is there a thread that can help you with what goes where.

Comment: There isn't such a thread because StackExchange is not a discussion forum. Other sites are just as "trustworthy" as StackExchange, and you're going to have to accept them if you want to ask the kinds of questions that are not permitted here.

Comment: @user3371655 if by "help you with what goes where" you mean determine what sorts of questions are appropriate for a given SE site, you can get that info from the [help center](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help)

Answer (score 2):

In some cases, one or more of the SE chat areas might be appropriate.

Comment: Gook point; I'd just add in this current context that one needs at least 20 rep to be allowed to chat.

Comment: True, you do need 20 rep. If OP or others think that's a barrier, I would refer them to this [meta question on how to earn rep for chat](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7248/how-do-you-get-20-rep-to-get-into-chat).